# perl Encode qw/encode decode/ redefined Encode.pm

Tags: perl, utf-8, encode, big5

I'm querying table "post"; its fields username and content are utf8 chinese. I need to convert them to big5 to print in windows console. My script fails to compile, reporting errors that the ENCODE routines are redefined.

I have another script to test encode/decode without DBI, and it works fine. How can I fix it?

The script:

```
use DBI;
use strict;
use ENCODE qw /encode decode/;

my $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:SQLite:dbname=tweetylicious.db","","",{sqlite_unicode => 1});
$dbh->do("PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON");

my $result_aref = $dbh->selectall_arrayref("SELECT * FROM post");

foreach my $user ( @$result_aref ) {
    my $name = ${$user}[1];
    my $content = ${$user}[2];
    print encode("utf8", $name), " : ",$content, "\n";
}
```

The errors:

```
subroutine DEBUG redefined at path-to-lib/ENCODE.pm line 144
subroutine encoding redefined at path-to-lib/ENCODE.pm line 164
...
```

Comment: After fixing `ENCODE` to `Encode` and creating a database with a dummy table, I was able to run the program, but I do not get the errors you described.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're on a case-insensitive filesystem (typically, on Windows), `use`ing a module with the wrong case can lead to such messages.

Short answer: `use Encode (...)` (note the capitalization)

Longer answer: Perl is case-sensitive.  When you [`use`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/use.html) a module using the wrong capitalization, the `require` part of the job will seek `ENCODE.pm`, load it and store it in `%INC`.  But when any other part of the code then attempts to `use` it under its proper name (for `Encode`, this happens through an `Encode`->`Encode::Alias`->`Encode` loop), it won't find it in `%INC`, will load it again, and that triggers all those redefinition messages.

Using the intended module name avoids this.